# Visual Studio JavaScript IntelliSense - Work in Object Oriented model

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

Given an oversimplified model of my object-oriented hierarchy:

```
var BaseObj = function (field) { this.field = field; };

var DescendentObject = function (field, field2) { 
  this.BaseObj(field); 
  this.field2 = field2; 
};

BaseObj.prototype = {
  ///<field name="field" type="String">I am well documented</field>
  field : ""
};

DescendentObject.prototype = {
  ///<field name="field" type="String">I am well documented</field>
  field2 : ""
};

//this simplies our actual inheritance model but effectively does the same thing
DescendentObject.prototype.BaseObj = BaseObj;
DescendentObject.prototype.field = BaseObj.prototype.field;

var x = new DescendentObject();
x.field2    //I am well documented
x.field     //editor knows I exist, but I am completely undocumented!
```

Is there any way to get that nice documentation for field in BaseObj into the field in DescendentObject without needing to explicitly list each field in both objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can put put instance intellisense on the BaseObj

```
var BaseObj = function (field) {
    ///<field name="field" type="String">I am well documented</field>
    this.field = field;
};
```

or use a non-object literal notation:

```
DescendentObject.prototype = new (function(){
    /// <field name="field" type="String">I am well documented</field>
    this.field2 = "";
})();
```

According to the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh542725.aspx,
this comment ignores the name attribute and automatically attaches to whatever is below it, because it is inside an object literal:

```
DescendentObject.prototype = {
  ///<field name="field" type="String">I am well documented</field>
  field2 : ""
};
```